# POST request not working in nodejs with expressjs and bodyparser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

I am new into nodejs and currently learning. I came across the problem where my POST req is not working. I made a simple html form to exercise the GET and POST req. However, the GET req is just working fine. How can I make the POST req run on browser or what is the issue here?
I would really appreciate some help/guidance from the experts.
thank you.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
   
    res.send("thanks for posting");
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("the port is working just fine");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post"></form>
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="first number">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="second number">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculator</button>

</body>
</html>
```

images are my HTML and node js codes.

[image: images are my HTML and node js codes.]

Comment: show POST request and response

Comment: sorry, didnt get you. Can you pls elaborate. @Anatoly

Comment: You shown a GET request on a screen shot. Can you add a POST request screenshot?

Comment: The problem is caused by a **typo**: You put the `</form>` tag **before** the form controls that should be inside the form.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Its fixed Thank you so very much @quentin

Comment: Now that problem is solved, someone should post the solution as an answer or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="first number">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="second number">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculator</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

the fixation to my issue.